# How to restore from truncated btrfs?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, btrfs

I'm suffering from the combination of two issues:

- after changing the HDD enclosure once and changing back to the initial enclosure (and others in order to test), a 5TB `btrfs` is now truncated after 2TB and can't be mounted anymore (based on 2TB I assume that a faulty Linux kernel hasn't recognized GPT correctly or that I missed something else and written the tail of a partition onto the disk)
- the HDD is partly damaged with > 8000 damaged blocks which can't be read (according to multiple runs of `ddrescue`

Even the tiniest error causes a `bad block` failure of `btrfs check` on both the HDD and the `ddrescue` image so that resizing won't work because mounting requires fixing the fs errors and `btrfs restore` doesn't accept the complete device as input. `btrfs restore` fails with

```
leaf parent key incorrect 29425664
Error searching -1
```

I assmue after reaching the device border looking for data outside the 2TB border.

I'm using `btrfs-progs` 4.2.3 Ubuntu 15.10 with Linux 4.2.5.

Comment: So switch back to the old enclosure?   Apparently the new one can't handle more than 2 TB.

Comment: That wasn't precise from my side. I used the enclosure only once when the truncation must have happened. Meanwhile I'm using the initial and tested others as well. The truncation seems to be final, though.

Comment: Where are you getting the size from?  What does `parted print` show?